# Android Studio: Dependencies versions

Tags: android, dependencies

Error highlighted by Android Studio `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`.

It writes "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version spec (mixing versiosn can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support-support-media-compact:25.2.0)

How could I actually know which import version is the most updated? The build-gradle is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using Android Studio 3.2 
Your build gradle should like this :

**buil.gradle(module:app) (androidx with Kotlin)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sanaebadi.info.databindinginkolinworld"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

   }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    // notice that the compiler version must be the same than our gradle version
    kapt 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'


}
```

---

**and your buil.gradle(Project:test)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()



    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

---

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Sun Sep 30 13:21:15 EDT 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip
```

your problem should be solve

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your dependency:

```
com.android.support-support-media-compact:28.0.0
```

Hope that will solve. If this type of problem caused again then you need to override the conflicted libraries by adding the conflicted libraries with the version(this time 28.0.0) in your gradle dependency.

Comment: AS reports error `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-media-compact:28.0.0`